# Burninate [pages] again

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

[pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pages) was [removed last year](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187401/burninate-pages-tags) but it came back and currently has 160 questions tagged under it. We need to burninate it again.

Comment: Question count shows `102` now..

Comment: Community at work :) Amazingly fast

Comment: `[pages]` is now number **284** on my keep-it-dead tag list.

Comment: @Charles how do you manage it? A user script or something?

Comment: @AzizShaikh, 16 bookmarks and a script to regenerate them when I hit the tags-per-page limit.  I'm working on an application that uses the SE API to do the monitoring for me, off and on.